# Vuelidate Two Forms In One Component

Tags: vue.js, validation, vuelidate

I want to validate two whole different forms in a single component. I created the two of them, configured the validations, the methods, data etc. Everything is fine, Moreover, both forms work acutally, but with a little problem. I wrote a little code to explain the problem I was having.

Here is my forms in the component.

```
  <!-- First Form -->
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="submitFormFirst">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input v-model="name" type="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" />
        <small v-if="!$v.name.required && $v.name.$dirty">This field is required.</small>
      </div>
      <!-- Save Button -->
      <button type="submit">Save Form 1</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- Second Form -->
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="submitFormSecond">
      <div>
        <label>Surname</label>
        <input v-model="surname" type="name" placeholder="Surname" />
        <small v-if="!$v.surname.required && $v.surname.$dirty">This field is required.</small>
      </div>
      <!-- Save Button -->
      <button type="submit">Save Form 2</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

As you can see there are two different forms and they have their own submit buttons. Here is my data looks like;

```
data() {
  return {
    name: null,
    surname: null,
  };
```

And my validations...

```
validations: {
  name: {
    required,
  },
  surname: {
    required,
  }
}
```

And at the end, I created two methods. One for Form1 and one for Form2.

```
methods: {
  submitFormFirst() {
    if (!this.$v.$invalid) {
      alert("First Form Submitted.");
      let form = {
        name: this.name,
      };
      console.log(form);
    } else {
      alert("First Form Error.");
    }
  },
  submitFormSecond() {
    if (!this.$v.$invalid) {
      alert("Second Form Submitted.");
      let form = {
        surname: this.surname,
      };
      console.log(form);
    } else {
      alert("Second Form Error.");
    }
  },
}
```

So they have their own methods as well, they are totally seperated from each other, or I do think in this way... The problem is, when the page loads I immadiately go an try to type something in the first form's input and click "Save". It sends the `"First Form Error"` message with the alert. Then I type something in the second form's input and submit it, then it works, it prints the data in console and sends "Submitted." message. So when I start from the first form, I get an error. When I write and submit the second form, the problem disappears. Then I try the first form again, I see that it works too. The same scenario happens when I start from the second form. In other words, the first form I tried to submit gives an error, then I submit the other form. When I get back to the form I tried first, I see that it works too. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

If you want validate two forms you can change method that submit:

```js
methods: {
  submitFormFirst() {
    this.$v.name.$touch()
    if (!this.$v.name.$invalid) {
      alert("First Form Submitted.");
      let form = {
        name: this.name,
      };
      console.log(form);
    } else {
      alert("First Form Error.");
    }
  },
  submitFormSecond() {
    this.$v.surname.$touch()
    if (!this.$v.surname.$invalid) {
      alert("Second Form Submitted.");
      let form = {
        surname: this.surname,
      };
      console.log(form);
    } else {
      alert("Second Form Error.");
    }
  },
}
```